# MySQL Java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Buen día, ayuda por favor, estoy a punto de lanzar mi laptop a la pared gracias a mysql en java. 
Presento problemas al realizar el update de un campo, me aparece:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation:
>   Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Vasilmanov'

He tratado de hacer modificaciones, pero ninguna de ellas a dado efecto. Acá esta el método que estoy usando:

```
public void ModificarPersona(int id, String nom1, String nom2, String ape1, String ape2) {
        try {
            try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE  persona  SET  nom1 = ?,  nom2 = ?,   ape1 = ?,  ape2  = ?  WHERE id  =  ?")) {
                pstm.setInt(1, id);
                pstm.setString(2, nom1);
                pstm.setString(3, nom2);
                pstm.setString(4, ape1);
                pstm.setString(5, ape2);
                int executeUpdate = pstm.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trata de poner los set en orden como lo has montado en la query: 
                `pstm.setString(1, nom1);
                pstm.setString(2, nom2);
                pstm.setString(3, ape1);
                pstm.setString(4, ape2);pstm.setInt(5, id);`

Comment: gracias, fue muy buena tu respuesta, me ayudo mucho

Comment: Si la respuesta soluciona tus dudas, deberías marcarla como aceptada para ayudar a otros usuarios. Revisa el [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que montas una `query` que lleva una serie de parámetros en un orden.

`PreparedStatement pstm = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE  persona  SET  nom1 = ?,  nom2 = ?,   ape1 = ?,  ape2  = ?  WHERE id  =  ?"))`

Pero luego en el seteo de las variables tienes otro orden distinto a la de la `query`. Por eso te da dicho error.

Para solucionarlo basta con poner el mismo orden:

`pstm.setString(1, nom1); 
 pstm.setString(2, nom2);
 pstm.setString(3, ape1); 
 pstm.setString(4, ape2);
 pstm.setInt(5, id);`

Comment: El orden en que aparecen las instrucciones no es importante, lo importante es que el parámetro numérico concuerde con la posición del *?* en el SQL (si es 1, reemplazará el primer *?*). La respuesta no lo deja claro.